# Render html (angularjs) on server and save as pdf

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf

Say I have a page URL which is dynamic e.g. http://www.example.com/transaction=123. Now, based on the transaction the HTML will be different. The output will be html page with transaction info. I need to execute this on server and then save output as PDF.

Any example, reference to do this with nodejs?

Can I use PhantomJS in visual studio? (like after rendering use phantomjs to save as pdf)?

Comment: Maybe you could write a program that will generate the html file on the server like you want passing the number. And use that with something like [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf/) to convert it?
Also, there seems to be a [NuGet package for PhantomJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/), so I would give that a try if you want to use PhantomJS with VS.

Comment: Yes, however, the page will still have angular place holder and not the actual value.